# Configure TypeORM with one configuration for CLI and NestJS application

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM in my NestJS application. My `app.module.ts` has a very standard setup and works:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigService } from './config/config.service';
import { ConfigModule } from './config/config.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],

      // @ts-ignore issues with the type of the database
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: configService.getDBType(),
        host: configService.getDBHost(),
        port: configService.getDBPort(),
        username: configService.getDBUser(),
        password: configService.getDBPassword(),
        database: configService.getDBName(),
        entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    ConfigModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here's the thing. If I want to run migrations on the CLI, I need to have an `ormconfig.js`. I do not wish to duplicate credentials in both `ormconfig.js` and in my `config.service.js`. I created a `.env` file that looks like the following:

```
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = mysql
TYPEORM_HOST = app-db
TYPEORM_USERNAME = user
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = password
TYPEORM_DATABASE = db-dev
TYPEORM_PORT = 3306
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = true
TYPEORM_LOGGING = true
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/**/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS = src/migrations/**/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_TABLE_NAME = migrations
```

Since env vars are now defined as depicted here: [TypeORM Documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md#using-environment-variables), I went ahead and refactored `app.module.ts` to look like the following:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), ConfigModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now I get errors that env vars `DATABASE_HOST`, `DATABASE_PORT` etc are missing when I use `typeorm cli`.

Here is my `config.service.ts`

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as Joi from '@hapi/joi';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { keys, pick } from 'lodash';

export type EnvConfig = Record<string, string>;

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  private readonly envConfig: Record<string, string>;

  constructor(filePath: string) {
    const envNames = keys(this.getJoiObject());
    const envFromProcess = pick(process.env, envNames);
    const envFromFile = fs.existsSync(filePath) ? dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath)) : {};
    const envConfig = Object.assign(envFromFile, envFromProcess);

    this.envConfig = this.validateInput(envConfig);
  }

  private validateInput(envConfig: EnvConfig): EnvConfig {
    const envVarsSchema: Joi.ObjectSchema = Joi.object(this.getJoiObject());

    const { error, value: validatedEnvConfig } = envVarsSchema.validate(envConfig);

    if (error) {
      throw new Error(`Config validation error: ${error.message}`);
    }

    return validatedEnvConfig;
  }

  private getJoiObject(): object {
    return {
      NODE_ENV: Joi.string()
        .valid('development', 'production', 'test', 'provision')
        .default('development'),
      PORT: Joi.number().default(3000),

      DATABASE_TYPE: Joi.string()
        .valid('mysql')
        .default('mysql'),

      DATABASE_HOST: Joi.string().required(),
      DATABASE_PORT: Joi.number().required(),
      DATABASE_NAME: Joi.string().required(),
      DATABASE_USER: Joi.string().required(),
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: Joi.string().required(),
    };
  }

  get(key: string): string {
    return this.envConfig[key];
  }

  getPort(): number {
    return parseInt(this.envConfig.PORT, 10);
  }

  getDBType(): string {
    return this.envConfig.DATABASE_TYPE;
  }

  getDBHost(): string {
    return this.envConfig.DATABASE_HOST;
  }

  getDBPort(): number {
    return parseInt(this.envConfig.DATABASE_PORT, 10);
  }

  getDBName(): string {
    return this.envConfig.DATABASE_NAME;
  }

  getDBUser(): string {
    return this.envConfig.DATABASE_USER;
  }

  getDBPassword(): string {
    return this.envConfig.DATABASE_PASSWORD;
  }
}
```

Are the `TYPEORM_` env vars mutually exclusive here? Do we really need to replicate the environment variables to their `DATABASE_` form in order to have TypeORM work in CLI and in the context of the NestJS application? This seems very wrong. What is the right way to have TypeORM work both CLI(I want this for migrations in development) and in the NestJS application without having to duplicate these variables?

Comment: Can you share your `configService` please

Comment: @RiajulIslam posted.

Answer (score 39):

My configuration.

- Without duplication of configuration declarations
- Without installing and requiring dotenv.

```js
// src/config/db.config.ts

import {registerAs} from "@nestjs/config";

export default registerAs('database', () => {
    return {
        type: "postgres",
        logging: true,
        host: process.env.DB_MAIN_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_MAIN_PORT),
        username: process.env.DB_MAIN_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_MAIN_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_MAIN_DATABASE,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        // synchronize: process.env.MODE === "dev",
        entities: ["src/**/*.entity.ts"],
        migrations: ['src/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
        cli: {
            migrationsDir: 'src/migrations'
        },
    }
})
```

```js
// app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import {ConfigModule, ConfigService} from '@nestjs/config';
import {TypeOrmModule} from "@nestjs/typeorm";

import dbConfiguration from "./config/db.config";

@Module({
  imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          load: [dbConfiguration],
      }),
      TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({...configService.get('database')})
      })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// ormconfig.ts

import {ConfigModule} from "@nestjs/config";
import dbConfiguration from "./src/config/db.config";

ConfigModule.forRoot({
    isGlobal: true,
    load: [dbConfiguration],
})

export default dbConfiguration()
```

it's require ts-node

```json
//package.json
"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
"typeorm:migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -n",
"typeorm:migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run"
```

Comment: super clean! this should be marked as the correct answer!

Comment: Spend some time here trying to figure out the best solution for that, this is the best I found by far! Thank you!

Comment: @Robert this is the best solution.

Comment: So many files... wowza.

Comment: You dont need to destructuring the config. Just simply return configService.get('database') is enough.

Comment: When I run `typeorm:migration:generate <MigrationName>` I get am getting `Missing required argument: dataSource` any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

### Solution

This solution allows you to use the same parameters for both CLI usage and application usage, without running into code duplication.

Use path.join():

#### config.service.ts

```js
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { join } from 'path';

// tslint:disable-next-line: no-var-requires
require('dotenv').config();

class ConfigService {

   constructor(private env: { [k: string]: string | undefined }) {}

   //...etc

  public getTypeOrmConfig(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {

      // obviously, change these if you're using a different DB
      type: 'postgres',
      host: this.getValue('POSTGRES_HOST'),
      port: Number(this.getValue('POSTGRES_PORT')),
      username: this.getValue('POSTGRES_USER'),
      password: this.getValue('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
      database: this.getValue('POSTGRES_DB'),

      entities: [join(__dirname, '**', '*.entity.{ts,js}')],

      migrationsTableName: 'migration',
      migrations: [join(__dirname, '..', 'migrations', '*.ts')],

      cli: {
        migrationsDir: '../migrations',
      },

      synchronize: true,
      ssl: this.isProduction(),
    };
  }
}

const configService = new ConfigService(process.env);

export default configService;
```

#### app.module.ts

If you use `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` with no arguments, this will by default look for an `ormconfig.json` file at the root of your project. You can provide it with a TypeOrmModuleOptions parameter as well, which I would recommend. I would suggest doing this exactly as Riajul Islam and Muhammad Zeeshan did:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(configService.getTypeOrmConfig()),
        // add other modules here as well
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### write-type-orm-config.ts

This is a simple script which allows you to generate the ormconfig.json file which is useful for CLI operations.

```js
import configService from '../src/config.service';
import fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync(
  'ormconfig.json',
  JSON.stringify(configService.getTypeOrmConfig(), null, 2), // last parameter can be changed based on how you want the file indented
);
```

### Project Structure

You will probably want to change the exact join statements for your `entities` and `migrations` properties based on your own file structure and how you name your entities.

My project structure is:

```
.env // ALL environmental variables are stored here, both for Node and for other processes such as Docker
src
   | config.service.ts
   | app.module.ts // calls configService.getTypeOrmConfig()
   | main.ts
scripts // for CLI only operations
   | seed.ts // calls configService.getTypeOrmConfig() when creating a ConnectionOptions object for the database
   | write-type-orm-config.ts // calls configService.getTypeOrmConfig() to create an ormconfig.json file at the root, which I use for some NPM scripts
migrations
   | DB migrations go here...
```

### Sample package.json Scripts

This is likely where you will need an ormconfig.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:dev:db:seed": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register scripts/seed.ts",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:dev:autoconfig": "yarn run typeorm:migration:run && yarn run start:dev:db:seed",
    "start:prod": "node dist/src/main",
    "pretypeorm": "(rm ormconfig.json || :) && ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register scripts/write-type-orm-config.ts",
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js",
    "typeorm:migration:generate": "yarn run typeorm -- migration:generate -n",
    "typeorm:migration:run": "yarn run typeorm -- migration:run"
  },
```

Note that you will have to specify a migration name when generating a migration: `yarn run typeorm:migration:generate ${MIGRATION_NAME}`

### References

https://medium.com/better-programming/typeorm-migrations-explained-fdb4f27cb1b3 (good article about configuring a TypeORM environment with NestJS) 
https://github.com/GauSim/nestjs-typeorm (Git repository for the above)

Answer (score 2):

*Improvement of FinallyStatic answer (not really, just using NestJs config docs).* I think it's just cleaner this way.

**db-config.ts**

```js
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { registerAs } from "@nestjs/config";
import { config as setConfig } from 'dotenv';

setConfig();
setConfig({ path: '.dev.env' }); // use this if you use another .env file. Take the two setConfig if you use .env + other.env

export default registerAs('typeOrmConfig', (): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST || 'localhost',
    port: Number(process.env.MYSQL_PORT) || 3306,
    username: process.env.MYSQL_USER || 'test',
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD || 'test',
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE || 'test',
    entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    charset: "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
    synchronize: false,
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: "src/migrations"
    },
    migrations: ["dist/migrations/**/*.js"],
}));
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import dbConfig from './config/db-config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.dev.env',
      load: [dbConfig]
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(dbConfig()),
    // etc...
  ],
  // etc...
});
```

**write-type-orm-config.ts**

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
import dbConfig from './config/db-config';

try {
    fs.unlinkSync('ormconfig.json');
}
catch { }
fs.writeFileSync(
    'ormconfig.json',
    JSON.stringify(dbConfig(), null, 4),
);
```

**package.json**

One line difference from FinallyStatic answer, so it's also Windows compatible with the `unlink` in the ts file.

```json
"pretypeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/write-type-orm-config.ts",
```

**Structure**

```
|-- src/
| |-- config/
| | |-- db-config.ts
| |
| |-- migrations/
| | |-- *migration files*
| |
| |-- app.module.ts
| |-- write-type-orm-config.ts
|
|-- .env
|-- ormconfig.json
```

Comment: What's the point of generating ormconfig.json when it exposes username and password data that are stored in .env?

Comment: Yeah yeah I did read. My question is why wouldn't I only use ormconfig.json...why bother with .ts config files if .json will be created anyway, thus exposing your username and password which you usually read from .env

Comment: Well you can, you have plenty of options, take a look at https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md. When I use it, I delete the json right after the migration, so I don't really have a duplicate. If for example you use docker you can place the envs inside the compose and you don't have to bother changing the json file because you don't have it. Also, you'd have always to remember that you have to do the json file when you install any nest server because it's bad practice to include it into the repo

Comment: Not to mention if you have different connections between local, staging and production, it can easily become a mess. That's my point of view but you can do as you want, if it was such a bad thing to do to make directly the json file, there won't be the option to do it or it would be discouraged

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come up with a solution that involves only two lines of code:
**ormconfig.ts**

```
import { AppConfig } from "./app.config";
export default AppConfig.getTypeOrmConfig();
```

Here's what I did: I firstly created an **app.config.ts** file, which will contain everything related to configuration through the AppConfig class.

This file also contains an **EnvironmentVariables** class, (which is used (in the **validateConfig** function of the **AppConfig** class) to perform validation of the **.env** file (check missing values) and value conversion (**POSTGRES_DB_PORT** variable would be cast to number for example).

Here's the code:
**app.config.ts**

```
import { join } from "path";
import { plainToClass } from "class-transformer";
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { MongooseModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { IsNumber, IsIn, validateSync, IsString } from "class-validator";

const enviroments = ["development", "test", "production"] as const;
type Environment = typeof enviroments[number];

class EnvironmentVariables {
  @IsIn(enviroments)
  NODE_ENV: Environment;

  @IsString()
  POSTGRES_DB_HOST: string;

  @IsNumber()
  POSTGRES_DB_PORT: number;

  @IsString()
  POSTGRES_DB_NAME: string;

  @IsString()
  POSTGRES_DB_USERNAME: string;

  @IsString()
  POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD: string;

  @IsString()
  MONGO_DB_URI: string;
}

export class AppConfig {
  private static get env(): EnvironmentVariables {
    return plainToClass(EnvironmentVariables, process.env, {
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    });
  }

  public static getTypeOrmConfig(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: "postgres",
      host: this.env.POSTGRES_DB_HOST,
      port: this.env.POSTGRES_DB_PORT,

      username: this.env.POSTGRES_DB_USERNAME,
      password: this.env.POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD,
      database: this.env.POSTGRES_DB_NAME,

      // the rest of your config for TypeORM
    };
  }

  public static get getMongooseUri(): string {
    return this.env.MONGO_DB_URI;
  }

  public static getMongooseConfig(): MongooseModuleOptions {
    return { useFindAndModify: false };
  }

  public static validateConfig(config: Record<string, unknown>) {
    const validatedConfig = plainToClass(EnvironmentVariables, config, {
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    });

    const errors = validateSync(validatedConfig, {
      skipMissingProperties: false,
    });

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw new Error(errors.toString());
    }

    return validatedConfig;
  }
}
```

Then, on the AppModule, all I needed to do was import the ConfigModule (which loads the enviroment variables from the .env file and perform validation of it using our validateConfig function) and set the configuration for TypeORM and Mongoose using the AppConfig class:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

import { AppConfig } from "./app.config";
import { AppService } from "./app.service";
import { AppController } from "./app.controller";


@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validate: AppConfig.validateConfig,
    }),

    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(AppConfig.getTypeOrmConfig()),

    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      AppConfig.getMongooseUri,
      AppConfig.getMongooseConfig(),
    ),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
})
```

And finally, for the ormconfig file, it was as simple as this:

**ormconfig.ts**

```
import { AppConfig } from "./app.config";

export default AppConfig.getTypeOrmConfig();
```

Here's also my project structure in case you need it:

```
project/
    src/
        app.config.ts
        app.controller.ts
        app.module.ts
        app.service.ts
        main.ts
        ormconfig.ts
        config
    .env
    package.json
    package.lock.json
```

And here are the scripts I added to package.json to use typeorm-cli:

```
"typeorm:cli": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/ormconfig.ts",
"run-migrations": "npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:run",
"create-migration": "npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:create --name",
"make-migrations": "npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:generate --pretty --name"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

To use both *TypeORM CLI* and *ConfigModule/ConfigService* seamlessly, I found this approach from improving *Robert* answer, without adding additional script like any above answer mentioned. I think this solution is more "**NestJS**" way and a cleaner solution as well.

1. Load the config as what has been Robert's answer exemplified.
2. Also load in your module (imports the ConfigModule and also the TypeOrmModule).
3. The additional step will be creating your own separate migration configuration file and merge with your database configuration like the example below.

```js
// src/config/migration.config.ts

/**
 * Load the dot env manually without the NestJS config module.
 */
config();

/**
 * Defines the migration configuration using TypeORM DataSource.
 */
export default new DataSource({
  ...dbConfig(), // or any name you use for your database config, this is the same object that you use for `registerAs()` method
  
  //* Additional config for your migration
  migrations: [__dirname + '/../database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  migrationsTableName: 'custom-name',
});
```

**The key step here is to load your environment variable first, without running the NestJS application to get the env variables from ConfigService**

4. And the last step is to add the CLI command to the package.json like this

```js
// package.json

"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
"migration:create": "npm run typeorm -- migration:create",
"schema:drop": "npm run typeorm -- schema:drop -d src/config/migration.config.ts",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -d src/config/migration.config.ts",
"migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run -d src/config/migration.config.ts",
"migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert -d src/config/migration.config.ts"
```

And whoala, you could use both TypeORM CLI to run the migration and load the TypeORM configuration inside the NestJS application with a single database configuration file **(no configuration file duplication)** which loads the same environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any problem with your code probably I am not able to do, I fetched the same problem I can provide you my code example hope it will helpful for you.

- 1. `.env`:

```
APP_PORT=
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = <mysql | mongodb | pg>
TYPEORM_HOST = 
TYPEORM_USERNAME = 
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = 
TYPEORM_DATABASE = 
TYPEORM_PORT = 
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = <true | false>
TYPEORM_LOGGING = <true | false>

TYPEORM_ENTITIES=**/*.entities.ts,src/**/*.entities.ts,src/**/*.entity.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS=database/migration/*.ts
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR=database/migration
```

- 2. `config.service.ts`

```
import {TypeOrmModuleOptions} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
// tslint:disable-next-line: no-var-requires
require('dotenv').config();

class ConfigService {
    constructor(private env: {[key: string]: string | undefined}) {}

    private getValue(key: string, throwOnMissing = true): string {
        const value = this.env[key];
        if (!value && throwOnMissing) {
            throw new Error(`config error - missing env.${key}`);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public ensureValues(keys: string[]) {
        keys.forEach(key => this.getValue(key, true));
        return this;
    }
    public getTypeOrmConfig(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
        return {
            type: 'mysql',
            keepConnectionAlive: true,
            host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
            port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT) || 3306,
            database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
            username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
            entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entities{.ts,.js}']
        };
    }
}

const configService = new ConfigService(process.env).ensureValues([
    'TYPEORM_DATABASE',
    'TYPEORM_USERNAME',
    'TYPEORM_PASSWORD'
]);

export {configService};
```

- 3. `app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(configService.getTypeOrmConfig()),
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Please let me know if this solution is working or not

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've manage to fix it. With a single configuration file I can run the migrations on application boostrap or using TypeOrm's CLI. The only mod on `package.json` is to pass the config file for typeorm.

**src/config/ormconfig.ts**

```js
import parseBoolean from '@eturino/ts-parse-boolean';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { join } from 'path';

dotenv.config();

export = [
  {
    //name: 'default',
    type: 'mssql',
    host: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_NAME,
    options: {
      instanceName: process.env.DEFAULT_DB_INSTANCE,
      enableArithAbort: false,
    },
    logging: parseBoolean(process.env.DEFAULT_DB_LOGGING),
    dropSchema: false,
    synchronize: false,
    migrationsRun: parseBoolean(process.env.DEFAULT_DB_RUN_MIGRATIONS),
    migrations: [join(__dirname, '..', 'model/migration/*.{ts,js}')],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'src/model/migration',
    },
    entities: [
      join(__dirname, '..', 'model/entity/default/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'),
    ],
  } as TypeOrmModuleOptions,
  {
    name: 'other',
    type: 'mssql',
    host: process.env.OTHER_DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.OTHER_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.OTHER_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.OTHER_DB_NAME,
    options: {
      instanceName: process.env.OTHER_DB_INSTANCE,
      enableArithAbort: false,
    },
    logging: parseBoolean(process.env.OTHER_DB_LOGGING),
    dropSchema: false,
    synchronize: false,
    migrationsRun: false,
    entities: [],
  } as TypeOrmModuleOptions,
];
```

**src/app.module.ts**

```js
import configuration from '@config/configuration';
import validationSchema from '@config/validation';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { LoggerService } from '@shared/logger/logger.service';
import { UsersModule } from '@user/user.module';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import ormconfig = require('./config/ormconfig'); //path mapping doesn't work here

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      cache: true,
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: validationSchema,
      load: [configuration],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig[0]), //default
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig[1]), //other db
    LoggerService,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**package.json**

```json
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./src/config/ormconfig.ts",
    "typeorm:migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -n",
    "typeorm:migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run"
  },
```

**Project structure**

```
src/
├── app.controller.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── config
│   ├── configuration.ts
│   ├── ormconfig.ts
│   └── validation.ts
├── main.ts
├── model
│   ├── entity
│   ├── migration
│   └── repository
├── route
│   └── user
└── shared
    └── logger
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

**#1 src/config/database.ts**

database configuration

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';
const config: ConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  ...
};
export default config;
```

**#2 src/config/index.ts**

complete configuration for application

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
export async function getConfig() {
  dotenv.config();
  return {
    database: (await import('./database')).default,
    /* ...config sections for other modules */
  };
}
```

**#3 ormconfig.ts**

...just a proxy for *src/config/database.ts*

```
import config from './src/config/database';
export = config;
```

**#4 src/app.module.ts**

```
import { getConfig } from './config/index';
...
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      ignoreEnvFile: true,
      load: [getConfig],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return configService.get<ConnectionOptions>('database');
      },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [...],
})
```

**#5 fix build**

Add *ormconfig.ts* to *excluded* in *tsconfig.build.json*.